# await with httpClient.GetAsync(url) and getting error System.NullReferenceException was unhandled

Tags: c#, async-await, httpclient

I am using `VS 2012` and set the target `framework 4.0.`

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetResponse(Uri url)             
{                 
    this.httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();                 
    HttpResponseMessage response = await this.httpClient.GetAsync(url);                 
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();             
}
```

Error:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
HResult=-2147467261
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source=Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack.Net4
StackTrace:
Server stack trace: at System.Web.ThreadContext.AssociateWithCurrentThread(Boolean  setImpersonationContext) at System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(Boolean setImpersonationContext) at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallbackPossiblyUnderLock(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state) at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallback(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state) at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.Post(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.<>c__DisplayClassa.<OnCompletedInternal>b__0(Task param0)
        Exception rethrown at [0]: at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__1(Object state)
           at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
           at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
           at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
           at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
           at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
           at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
      InnerException: 
    -------------------------------------------------
```

I have installed `"Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack`" from `NuGet`, but still getting this error. Any suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried using [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) instead of Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack?

Comment: yes, i used Microsoft.Bcl.Async [link](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) as well but still getting same error.

Comment: Take a look at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396981/exception-using-await-httpclient-getasync-in-portable-class-library). May be it will help you.